# Incluir "." ou "," da direita para a esquerda de números inteiros

Tags: r

Eu tenho um vetor com os seguintes valores inteiros (ou strings):

```
x <- c("1781818", "178181800", "92561781818", "1781810")
```

Gostaria de colocar um ponto ou vírgula para separar os dois últimos dígitos, para que fiquem assim:

```
y <- c("17818.18", "1781818.00", "925617818.18", "17818.10")
```

Já pesquisei o uso da função `format`  e `readr::parse_number` , mas não achei uma solução ainda.

Answer (score 3):

As funções `formatC` e `sprintf` podem ser úteis para esse problema.

```
formatC(as.numeric(x)/100, digits = 2, 
        decimal.mark = ".", format = "f")
#[1] "17818.18"     "1781818.00"   "925617818.18"
#[4] "17818.10"

sprintf("%0.02f", as.numeric(x)/100)
#[1] "17818.18"     "1781818.00"   "925617818.18"
#[4] "17818.10"
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o pacote `str`,

```
str_c(str_sub(x, start = 1, end = -3), str_sub(x, start = -2), sep = ".")
```

A função `str_c` concatena `strings`, com um determinado separador (utilizei `,`).

A função `str_sub` extrai `substrings` de um `character`, só é necessário especificar onde se inicia e onde termina.